# Multiple regression model

Tags: regression, time-series

I have a multiple regression equation which as four quarters (maybe called them as parameters)

```
quartt = beta_0 + beta_1*t + beta_2*(t^2) + beta_3*Q_1 + beta_4*Q_2 + beta5*Q_3 + error_t
```

R result:

```
Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 276.6363 35.0485 7.893 3.43e-09 ***
t -7.4582 3.3960 -2.196 0.034999 *
I(t^2) 0.3012 0.0803 3.751 0.000657 ***
as.factor(Q)1 65.7707 27.1592 2.422 0.020933 *
as.factor(Q)2 -37.8701 27.0958 -1.398 0.171275
as.factor(Q)3 -127.6113 27.0574 -4.716 3.99e-05 ***
---
Residual standard error: 60.47 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.7443, Adjusted R-squared: 0.7067
F-statistic: 19.8 on 5 and 34 DF, p-value: 3.303e-09
```

Question:

1. E(quartt|Q3) = beta_0 +beta_1*t + beta_2*(t^2) + beta_5*(Q_3) Is it correct?
2. Do the independent variables, t, t^2, and Q in the model statistically significant?

I think they do since the P-value of F-test is small enough to reject the null by using alpha = 0.05. However, can I say even though the p-value of Q2 is not less than alpha, since Q1 and Q3 are less than alpha, we can say that Q is statistically significant simultaneously?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have fitted a model in R. You might not be able to conclude significance of such nominal variables until you look at an anova table.Hypothetical example `fit=lm(quartt~t+t^2+Q1+Q2+Q3)#model fit.
anova(fit) #this will give you joined significance`.